# Force rsync to don't show identifical files

Tags: rsync

I have a lengthy rsync that, when showing the out (what files it transfers), I would like it to only show files that differed from source to destination (i.e. actually changed). I want it to leave out files which were identical.

**NOTE:** I do not want to actually change what files are getting transferred - I just don't want to see it in the logs so I can focus on the files that rsync did change.

Comment: How are you using `rsync`? What command line options are you using?

Comment: rsync -avz -e ssh /some/path/ webadmin@ip:/remote/path

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue then. Without `-v` it would not display anything other than errors. `-v` would only display files that are being transferred. `-vv` would also display files that are being skipped. So, either the files are not being skipped, or you accidentally used `-vv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identical files are not synced, by `rsync` and thus do not appear in the output (log).

The problem, you're trying to solve, doesn't exist!

Comment: Are you sure? Because we will do an rsync of maybe 1,000 files, and they all show up, but only 2 or 3 actually changed...

Comment: I just realized I'm using -v for increased verbosity. That's probably it. Sorry!